# MyPy Doesn't Allow a Generic Attribute To Be Marked as Final

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to create a class which has an attribute that should be a constant. This attribute could have different types depending on were the class is used in the codebase. Moreover, the type of this attribute is used in various type hints throughout the class¹, so I decided to convert the class to a `Generic`, like so:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Final

T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    bar: Final[T]
    def __init__(self, bar: T) -> None:
        self.bar = bar
```

However, MyPy complains saying that

> Final name declared in class body cannot depend on type variables

while if I remove the `Final` annotation MyPy doesn't raise any errors.

I can't find any logical errors in my code: it simply says that, regardless of its type, the `bar` attribute should always be referencing the same object. Am I missing something or is this some limitation of Python and/or of MyPy?

¹In the example I'm showing only one such usage to keep things simple.

P.S. I'm using Python 3.10.8 and MyPy 0.991.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct per PEP591, `mypy` applies the rules in a wrong order, annotate in `__init__` to solve the issue.

Here are the links to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final) and [PEP591](https://peps.python.org/pep-0591/).

`mypy` should've checked the presence of initializer and then decide whether the initializer is missing, but it doesn't in fact and thinks that you define a final class attribute despite missing initializer. Type variables make no sense in types of class attributes (because type variables are bound to instances, not classes), so `mypy` errors here.

Thus we need to help `mypy` resolve the kind of `Final` properly. To do so, we can annotate attribute in `__init__` instead:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Final

_T = TypeVar("_T")

class Foo(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self, bar: _T):
        self.bar: Final[_T] = bar
```

This typechecks now ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=34e40e1e30cbaf09623b3dde7b3c2f61)).

Comment: My man answering at the same time... :-D Note that there is actually already an issue for this. See my answer.

Comment: Ough:( 
Thanks! I removed the paragraph about new issue.

Comment: I was not sure at first, but it seems as though this is not a bug, but intentional for some reason. But I think this issue thread needs to be bumped nonetheless. Nobody from the team has yet given an explanation for this.

Comment: Hm, that's really interesting, that the issue was opened as feature request. I don't see any signs why this should be denied, looks more like a false-positive bug. That thread certainly needs a bit more attention.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I have bumped the issue on GitHub. I hope that the MyPy maintainers implement this feature, but I'm afraid that they are busy with Python 3.11.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a known restriction of `mypy` and a loosening of this restriction was mentioned in [this feature request](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8982) over two years ago. It seem to be a rather niche problem judging from the lack of discussion around it, but you can always participate there. (I would say after such a long time since the last activity in that thread, you might respectfully bump it, if you include a reasonable use case and explain why you would want this feature as well.)

This restriction around [`typing.Final`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final) is not [documented by `mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/final_attrs.html), so at least that might be worth a mention.

The current workaround seems to be to omit the annotation in the class namespace and just annotate the instance attribute during assignment inside the `__init__` method like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Final


T = TypeVar("T")


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, bar: T) -> None:
        self.bar: Final[T] = bar


class SubA(Foo[T]):
    def __init__(self, bar: T) -> None:
        self.bar = bar


class SubB(Foo[int]):
    bar = 42
```

This works as expected and `mypy` gives us an error for the attempt to re-assign `bar`:

```
error: Cannot assign to final attribute "bar"  [misc]
error: Cannot assign to final name "bar"  [misc]
```